# Number validation failure in SpringBoot Rest API

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I'm building a SpringBoot Rest API and I have a filed amount in My RequestDTO of type BigDecimal However When pass { "amount": "1234.5"} like this(here I'm passing amount as String) I want to throw IllegalArgumentException or any kind of Exception , It Should work fine when Pass { "amount": 1234.5} from My Postman,

I have tried Multiple ways Still no Luck

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view this is expected behaviour. Spring will automatically map values to their expected type when deserializing the request body. In addition, Spring will also throw 4xx error if the request body can not be deserialized properly. For example, if you send `{"amount":"abcd"}` you should see a 4xx in postman.

Having said that, if you still want to implement a custom validator, you can do that by overriding `isValid` method from `ConstraintValidator` interface. You can check [this tutorial](https://blog.tericcabrel.com/write-custom-validator-for-body-request-in-spring-boot/amp/) for the steps on how to acieve it.